# SQL DataType Conversion Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, type-conversion

I am trying this code:

```
DECLARE @testID varchar(max)
set @testID = '1,2,3'

Delete from [Test] where [Test_ID] in (@testID)
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

Can anyone please help....

Comment: When you put something between ' and ' it means string in sql.

Answer (score 1):

Your query compiles to

```
Delete from [Test] where [Test_ID] in ('1,2,3')
```

but it should be

```
Delete from [Test] where [Test_ID] in ('1','2','3')
```

You can't put a **single** string into the `IN` clause. Use seperate values.

Comment: :)  I didn't notice that... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
declare @testID varchar(max)
set @testID =1,2,3
set @testID='delete from [Test] where [Test_ID] in('+@testID+')'
exec(@testID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @testID VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @testID = '1,2,3';
DELETE FROM [Test] WHERE ',' + @testID + ',' LIKE '%,' + [Test_ID] + ',%'
```

**OR**

```
DELETE FROM [Test] WHERE [Test_ID] IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delete query should be like

```
Delete From [Test] Where [Test_ID] in (1,2,3)
```

but you **cant** because your parameter is a csv format. so you have to make a list of int. and delete record that contains in this list.

Try this:

```
declare @xml xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@testID ,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
Delete From [Test] Where [Test_Id] in (
select * from(select t.value('.','int') as ID from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as a(t)) r

)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way...Please refer below...

```
  DECLARE @testID varchar(max)
 DECLARE @testExec varchar(max)
set @testID = '1,2,3'
Set @testExec = 'Delete from IMPCT_INTAKE_REQ where IMPCT_INTAKE_ID in ('+@testID+')'
print @testExec
execute (@testExec)
```